# cd command doesn't work in Dymola.mos file

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to configure dymola.mos file,  here is an example of changing directory, but when I activate Dymola, it seems the working directory doesn't change at all, even though the log shows Dymola run the script.
My question is:
How could I make the cd command work in the dymola.mos file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have activated the option *Save startup directory*. You can check this with the flag `Advanced.StartupDirectory`, which will be either 1 or 2. You can simply turn that off or follow the steps below.

From your command log we see that:

1. Dymola first executes the script `<install-path/insert/dymola.mos`
2. Then it restores the settings stored in `setup.dymx`

Hence the settings in `setup.dymx` override your working directory.

Instead of using `<install-path/insert/dymola.mos` you should use a custom `.mos` script, which is passed as first argument to `dymola.exe` on startup. This will always be executed last.

#### Example for Windows

- Create the file `startup.mos` somewhere, e.g. in `C:\dymola\startup.mos`
- Create a shortcut to `Dymola.exe`, (for Dymola 2021x: `C:\Program Files\Dymola 2021x\bin64\Dymola.exe`)
- Add the .mos script as argument in the `Target field` in the properties of the shortcut. The result will be:
  `"C:\Program Files\Dymola 2021x\bin64\Dymola.exe" "C:\dymola\startup.mos"`